# place search api for nokia maps in http format?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I need an api for nokia maps place search with query and place term.

The API should be in http(url) format.

like this:

http://api.nokia.com/query=hotels/location=lat,long

Comment: Searching `Google` came up with a lot of results... http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Maps_API_-_Add_Maps_To_Any_Web_Page being one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be after the RESTful Places API. The latest documentation can be found here: http://developer.here.net/places

If you are after hotels, you could base your query on the example here:

http://developer.here.net/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-rest/places-search/places-search-by-category.html

The following URL will return a set of hotels in central Berlin (around 52.51N,13.4E)

http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/explore?cat=hotel&at=52.51,13.4&app_id=_peU-uCkp-j8ovkzFGNU&app_code=gBoUkAMoxoqIWfxWA5DuMQ&accept=application/json

Answer (score 0):

See this link http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=19.1273%2C72.8515&tf=plain&size=10&app_id=7vivA7jIFlZh9WX_B0cd&app_code=6ptUAobtF0RFJ9CkfX7geg&Geolocation=geo%3A19.0254%2C72.8401%3Bcgen%3Dmap . You can customize your search on left panel